# Why does @Documented annotation have runtime retention?

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

As I know, `@Documented` annotation is used only by javadoc generator to generate javadocs from sources. So retention type should be `SOURCE`, but it's `RUNTIME`. Why?

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Documented {
}
```

Comment: Javadoc isn't the only documentation generation tool in existence.  Other tools may be capable of generating documentation from classes without the need for source.

Comment: IMO that does not explain why `@Documented` needs runtime retention, since runtime means that this annotation can be processed while the program is running in the JVM, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

> IMO that does not explain why @Documented needs runtime retention

Yes, it does. Lets say I ship a jar file without the sources. A user can build a proper javadoc using only information from classfiles the the reason that classfile have proper annotations is becase they are RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's query.